# Algolia Search Delete Replica Index with API

Tags: php, api, algolia

I am getting an error when trying to delete a replica index - `cannot apply a delete request on a replica index`

I have tried deleting the index after removing it from the settings, but cannot get it to work unless I `sleep(1)`.  This works, but I hoped there would be some way to force delete the replica without using `sleep`.

```
$index->setSettings(['replicas' => []]);
sleep(1);
$client->deleteIndex('someindex');
```

Does anyone know of a way to force delete a replica index?

Sources:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/replicas/
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/delete-index/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the `waitTask` in the documentation - https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/wait-task/

So waiting until the replica is removed in the settings before deleting would look like:

```
$res = $index->setSettings(['replicas' => []]);
$index->waitTask($res['taskID']);
$client->deleteIndex('someindex');
```

Comment: @vvo  - Yes, deleting a replica can be done via the method above